# Where do I get the Python DLLs for Visual Studio?

Tags: python, c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, include

This is probably a pretty stupid question but surprisingly I have been unable to find any information about it (partly due to there being so many different variations on the theme of Python & C clogging up my search results).

I want to build an application in C++ that can be extended using Python. To this end the application should able to execute Python scripts which can in turn call methods provided by the application. I specifically want to be able to do this on Windows.

I've examined the source of the Blender project (http://www.blender.org) and I found a set of header files from Python and some binaries (python34.dll, python34.lib). Where do I get these binaries officially? I can't find a package of them anywhere, nor can I work out if one of the source packages is supposed to compile into them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are part of the Python 3.4 Windows installation. The library file is in c:\python34\libs and the DLL is in c:\python34\DLLs. Assuming c:\python34 is the Python installation folder.

Comment: The lib file appears to be about right but the only dll (other than the tcl/tk and sqlite3 ones) in the DLLs folder is absolutely tiny (71KB) compared to the one I got from Blender which is 3MB. Also the Blender one is called python34.dll while the one in the DLLs folder is called python3.dll

Comment: @user573949 python34.dll is installed to C:\Windows\System32\ -- mine is 3.86M.